# A question on Hamming metric/distance

Tags: combinatorics, metric-spaces

Suppose $\sf{X}=\{0,1\}$, and $\sf{X}^n$ is the set of all binary sequences of length $n$. So the **first question** is that what does it mean by the *convex closure* of a subset $\sf{A}$ of $\{0,1\}^n$, which is denoted by $\sf{\bar{A}}$?

As usual, we define the Hamming distance of two subsets $\sf{A}$ and $\sf{B}$ of $\sf{X}^n$ can be defined as $d_H(\sf{A},\sf{B}) = \min_{\bf{x}\in \sf{A},\hat{\bf{x}}\in\sf{B}}$ $d_H(\bf{x},\bf{\hat{x}})$, where $d_H(\bf{x},\bf{\hat{x}})$ is the number of differences between binary sequences $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{\hat{x}}$.

Now define $\Gamma\sf{A} = \{\bf{x}: \bf{x} \in \sf{X}^n$, $d_H(\{\bf{x}\},\sf{A})\leq1\}$, and then define the *Hamming boundary* $\partial\sf{A}$ of $\sf{A}\in X^n$ as $\partial\sf{A} = \sf{A} \cap$ $\Gamma\sf{\bar{A}}$.

So the **second question** is that why do we use $\Gamma\sf{\bar{A}}$ instead of $\Gamma\sf{A}$ in the above definition?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that $\overline{A}$ means the convex closure for the second part?

What would make lots of sense would be if $\overline{A}$ is the complement of $A$ (which is a pretty standard notation in many set theory books):
Then

$$\partial A= \{ x \in A | \exists y \notin A \, \mbox{such that} \, d_H(x,y)=1 \} \,.$$

And this would represent the boundary in some sense.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. $\sf{\bar{A}}$ is the complement of $\sf{A}$, so that $\partial \sf{A} = \{\bf{x}:\bf{x} \in \sf{A},$ $d_H(\{\bf{x}\},\sf{\bar{A}})=1\}$.@N.S.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to the first question, but for the second question, $A$ is a subset of $\Gamma A$, so $A\cap\Gamma A$ is just $A$.

But I'm a little puzzled here, as, whatever the convex closure of $A$ is, I'd expect it to include $A$, and then the boundary of $A$ would still just be $A$. So, what is your source for the term, "convex closure" (in the context of binary sequences)? Does it really not give a definition, or illustrative example?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The notion $\sf{\bar{A}}$ should be the complement of $\sf{A}$. @Gerry Myerson

Comment: So why don't you edit the question so it makes sense? This information shouldn't be solely in the comments.